# Acceleration is the same for an object on two ends of a taut string

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, acceleration, free-body-diagram, string

Why is acceleration is the same for an object on two ends of a taut string in the analysis of dynamical systems? It's intuitive if the string is moving in a straight line, but not so if the string is curved over the side of a table or something like that. Please provide some rigorous justification if possible using Newton's. second law of motion represented by $F=ma$.

Comment: Voting to reopen since the question is perfectly clear. The accelerations of the two ends of the string are only equal *in magnitude* if the string is taut and follows a fixed path. This is justified by geometry, not dynamics.  If the string's path is not fixed (e.g. pendulum) then its two ends may have different magnitudes of acceleration.

Comment: The question could benefit from some clarification. What specific situation is meant with "if the string is curved over the side of a table or something like that". Is the question asking why the size of the force on the two ends is identical if those ends have a different orientation because the string runs over a fixed pulley in the middle?

Answer (score 1):

The acceleration doesn't always have to be the same but 99% of the time at least in introductory problems they are the same on both sides because the string itself doesn't stretch and doesn't have mass, so in order for the string or rop to not stretch, it requires the acceleration to be constant.

An example would be imagine if there was a block that was attached to another block over a table and connected by a pulley and rope system. In this case if the accelerations of the blocks were different the rope size would change.

Lets imagine the bottom block accelerating at 2 m/s^2 and top at 1 m/s^2 hypothetically. If this were the case the bottom block would travel more distance which would not have been covered by top block and assuming no initial velocity,the difference in displacement for 1 second is 0.5 a meter.

Of course in the real world the string can stretch, leading to differing accelerations which can make problems more complicated.

But the fundamental concept to remember is that if the rope or string doesn't change in size then acceleration is constant between two sides of the rope otherwise it can change though depending on other forces involved.

Answer (score 1):

The accelerations of the two ends of the string are only equal *as vectors* if the string is both taut and straight throughout the motion.

The accelerations of the two ends of the string will be equal *in magnitude* (although not necessarily in direction) if the string is taut and follows a fixed path. This is justified by geometry, not dynamics - the argument uses the fact that the path length between the two ends along the fixed path of the string is constant.

However, if the string's path is not fixed then its two ends may have different magnitudes of acceleration. For example, if end A of the string is fixed and end B is attached to a swinging mass (i.e. a pendulum) then the acceleration of end A is zero and the acceleration of end B is not zero.

Answer (score 0):

I emphasize a subtle distinction not captured in the original question. The key point is that the magnitudes of the acceleration vectors of object 1 and object 2 are equal.

Consider two objects: one light with mass $m_1$ and one heavy with mass $m_2$. The light object is held stationary, while the heavy object dangles from a string. Your hand exerts an upward force to balance the gravitational force acting on both objects, resulting in zero acceleration.

Now, if two objects are connected by a taut rope of fixed length $L$, and object 1 moves a distance $x_1(t)$ as a function of time, then object 2 moves $x_2(t)$. To ensure this separation of $L$ is maintained, it is crucial that the magnitudes are equal at all times (*i.e.* $x_1(t) = x_2(t)$ for all $t$).

The mathematics involved is as follows:

$$x_1(dt) = v dt + \frac{1}{2} a dt^2.$$

This equation can be simplified into a system of three ordinary differential equations (ODEs):

$$x_1(dt) = \frac{dx_1}{dt} dt + \frac{1}{2} \frac{d^2x_1}{dt^2} dt^2,$$
$$\frac{dx_1}{dt} = v_1,$$
$$\frac{dv_1}{dt} = a_1,$$

for which a unique solution exists. Since the displacements are equal $x_1(t) = x_2(t)$ for all $t$, their derivatives must also match, meaning that $v_1(t) = v_2(t)$ for all $t$. Consequently, the accelerations of the two objects must also be equal $a_1(t) = a_2(t)$ for all $t$.

Answer (score 0):

The inertia of the string is assumed to be negligible. Suppose then generally that a body supplies a force ${\bf F}_1$ at one end of the string, on the boundary point of the string. Another body supplies a force ${\bf F}_2$ at the other end of the string.

Take the string including its two boundary points as a free-body. It has no force due to weight since we already assumed it was inertia-less relative to the other bodies in the problem. Therefore, despite the fact that the string is accelerating, Newton's second law for a massless string becomes ${\bf F}_1 + {\bf F}_2 = {\bf 0}$. Hence, ${\bf F}_1 = - {\bf F}_2$.

This applies everywhere throughout the string. Just take a free-body where you cut on an interior point of the string and expose an exterior boundary point. The neighboring interior point of the string that you just cut away from supplies a tension in order to balance ${\bf F} = m {\bf a}$ for the isolated body which has $m=0$. Hence, there is a constant tension ${\bf T}$ acting throughout the massless string. This is the same force the string exerts on the connecting bodies and, by Newton's third law, is the same force the connecting bodies exert on the string.

Note that whenever you cut at an interior point of the string, ${\bf T}$ must point away from the material, as we assume the string only resists tension, not compression, so that it can only develop a constraint force in tension. Thus it is the magnitude $T$ which is constant throughout, with the direction $\frac{\bf T}{T}$ always pointing away from the material depending on how you take your cut.

Edit: I just realized you were asking a different question, probably involving pulleys. In that case, enforce the constant-length constraint of the string. Write down an expression involving the total length in terms of two variable lengths, and then take the time derivative of the length and set it to zero.